# I have a php file that connects to mysql database, will it be a security risk if someone knew the adress of this file?

Tags: php, mysql, security

The file is included on other pages that needs to query the database,

I believe including this file anywhere else won't be sufficient to access my database, but if someone managed to read the content of the file as .txt if might be an issue.

Is there a possibility for this happening ?

Comment: You have to, at least, put this file outside the web root. Have you?

Comment: You need to take measures to prevent anyone from accessing your PHP files directly, or reading directory contents. Just part of normal security measures.

Comment: Yes. there is a possibility to extract the contents based on your server configuration and settings. You need to take precautions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [inocube](http://www.ioncube.com/) to encrypt your php scripts. Then your clients are also not able to read any php script in your application.

Comment: Note that this is not the security best practice. It may be marginally useful for an additional layer, but everything else proposed in comments  (files outside of webroot, etc.) is better and more standard. By definition, encryption on the server where it needs to run must be reversible for the web server user (otherwise it would be impossible to run such code), so an attacker can decrypt it the same way. However, the encryption layer brings its own risks (3rd party dependency, vulnerabilities in the encryption layer, etc.)